# Any reason my temperature list won't let me check high and low limits?

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, iteration

Here is my code

```
  Temperatures=[]
  Hours = int(input("Enter hours in the day: "))

  for i in range(Hours):
      Temperatures.append(int(input('Enter temperature: ')))
      while(Temperatures > -50 and Temperatures < 150):
          print(Temperatures)
          if (-50 > Temperatures > 150):
              print("Re-Enter Temperature")
```

The error I get is

```
    while(Temperatures > -50 and Temperatures < 150):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

I'm not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Honestly even getting past the unsupported types issue. The while loop and the re-entering of temps isn't going to work the way you want it to. You need to do the check before you add it to the temperatures array

Comment: So adding the append to the end of the loop if the numbers are within the range I want?

Comment: I posted an answer since it was a little too indepth to answer in a comment.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, as the error says, you are trying to compare a list with an integer. 
If you want to access specific values inside of the list, you need to use index position. 
A way to solve this error is:

```
  Temperatures=[]
  Hours = int(input("Enter hours in the day: "))

  for i in range(Hours):
      while(Temperatures[i] > -50 and Temperatures[i] < 150):
      Temperatures.append(int(input('Enter temperature: ')))
          print(str(Temperatures[i]))
          if (-50 > Temperatures[i] > 150):
              print("Re-Enter Temperature")
```

Comment: you're missing where he did the same thing in the if statement as well

Comment: Thank you for that help but now it won't prompt to re-enter the temperature if it is outside of the limits I set. Essentially I am trying to get the user to enter the number of hours in a day within a set number of temperature ranges and then force a re-entry if the number is outside of that range. Then display the time of day along with the coinciding temperatures. I'm just lost here and very new to Python and programming in general.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my post again. Please tell me if this works, or if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few issues here. You are comparing a list to an int.

You are also adding the value to the array before you even check to see if it is a valid value. So you will add the values even if they are outside your acceptable ranges.

Doing the verification before adding it to the array takes care of both of those issue and also makes it so you don't have to worry about he index. Since you won't be using the index, it's better to change the for loop variable to an underscore.

```
Temperatures=[]
# The try-catch/if-else that I do for the input below should be done here to clean user input
Hours = int(input("Enter hours in the day: "))

for _ in range(Hours): # Changed this to underscore since we don't use it.
    valid_temp = False # used to continuously get temps until you get a valid one.

    while not valid_temp:
        # This is the try-catch if-else that I mentioned above
        # Here we split up the input to handle different issues.
        temp_in = input('Enter temperature: ')
        try:
            # Checking that a number was entered instead of a string or something else.
            temp_in = int(temp_in)
        except ValueError:
            print('Temperatures must be numeric')
            # Since a number was not entered this skips to the next iteration of the while loop
            continue

        # Checks if it's in a valid temp.
        if temp_in > -50 and temp_in < 150:
            Temperatures.append(temp_in)
            print(Temperatures)
            # Terminates the loop since a valid temp was entered.
            valid_temp = True
        else:
            print('Please Re-Enter Temperature')
            # Since a valid temp was not entered the while loop is started over.
            continue
```

Comment: Thank you it definitely does work for getting the temperatures. I will try to work out connecting it to the hours in the day. Ultimately I want it to print the temperatures received next to the hour in the days. Something sort of like this

Hour                          Temperature
00:00                                42
01:00                                42

Comment: I don't know if that that helped explain it.

Comment: Honestly since you are matching hours to temperatures, you probably want a different data structure than using two seperate arrays. Any number of things could happen to make the arrays not match up anymore. Maybe try a dictionary or a list of tuples. I probably would use a list of tuples here, because you won't really be using most of the functionality of a dict and dicts are NOT ordered by how you input data into them.